# Java, LibGDX, and JBox2d: Resizing a window while maintaining the aspect ratio of the objects being drawn

Tags: java, libgdx, aspect-ratio, window-resize, jbox2d

I am conducting a learning experiment with Java. I am attempting to create a simple "Megaman" style game using Java and the 3rd party API "LibGDX". I have obtained a rather solid understanding of the relationship between the `OrthographicCamera` object from LibGDX and the `World` object from LibGDX's implementation of "JBox2d".

However, when I resize the window the  objects inside `World` stretch. I have made use of the `resize(int width, int height)` method of the `Screen` interface. Inside of which i reset the `OrthographicCamera`'s width and height. This does not seem to have any effect of the way the images looks or behaves in the physics simulation.

So my question is this: **How do i properly resize a LibGDX/JBox2d application's window without distorting the objects being simulated?**

here is the code (in the form of a git repo because i find GitHub faster, easier, and kinder to the SO server...)

---

**EXTERNAL LINK**

https://gist.github.com/konnerdroid/8113302

**EXTERNAL LINK**

Answer (score 0):

AHA!!!! i wasnt updating my camera...

For any changes made to the camera to be visible and their effect to be felt you need to call `camera.update()` either in your loop or after any changes are made

well... at least i learned how to use github =)